# Scheme procedure to check the sum of cubes is equal to square of sum conjecture

Tags: scheme

I am trying to write an iterative procedure that returns #t if the sum of cubes is equal to square of sum is true, otherwise #f when the first integer <= n and the conjecture is false.

```
(define (square x) (* x x))
(define (cube x) (* x x x))

(define (conjecture n)
  (define (iter count result_c result_s)
    (cond ((= n 0) #f)
          (else (iter (+ count 1) (= (cube (+ count 1)) (square (+ count 1))) #t))))
  (iter 1 0 0))
```

My code always return #f. How should I fix it?

Comment: [Algebra Fact](https://twitter.com/AlgebraFact/status/976194313217626113). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps writing down the "square of sum" and "sum of cubes" functions separately might help you see better how you can combine them.

Suppose we wanted to square the sum from 1 to n, ie: `(1 + 2 + ... + n)²`. We could write a function as follows:

```
(define (square-of-sum a b acc)
  (if (> a b)
      (sqr acc)                                    ;; square the sum upon return
      (square-of-sum (add1 a) b (+ acc a))))
```

Similarly, to sum the cubed values from 1 to n, ie: `1³ + 2³ + ... + n³`, we could write:

```
(define (sum-of-cubed a b acc)
  (if (> a b)
      acc
      (sum-of-cubed (add1 a) b (+ acc (expt a 3)))))
```

So combining them to your desired effect would look as follows:

```
(define (combined a b cubed-acc sum-acc )
  (if (> a b)
      (= cubed-acc (sqr sum-acc))
      (combined (add1 a) b (+ cubed-acc (expt a 3)) (+ sum-acc a))))
```

The `combined` function above corresponds to your `iter`, and `conjecture` can be re-written as:

```
(define (conjecture n)
  (define (iter count cube-sum sum)
    (cond
      ((> count n)
       (= cube-sum (sqr sum)))
      (else
       (iter (add1 count)
             (+ cube-sum (expt count 3))
             (+ sum count)))))
  (iter 1 0 0))
```

then for any natural number `n`, you will have:

```
(conjecture n)
=> #t
```